# javascript: dosent show arrays in html

Tags: javascript, arrays

i would show values list array at html id
why console tell me show is null and dosent show them?!

```
<script>
  var howMany = prompt("how many do you want to buy?");
  var goods = "";
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0 ; i < howMany ; i++){
      goods = prompt("add a name ?");
      list.push(goods);
  }

  var show = document.getElementById("des");
  show.innerText = list;
```

Comment: Your html, please?

Comment: Well, do you have an element with `id="des"` somewhere?

Comment: @acdcjunior  yes i have

Comment: Maybe the problem is the "innerText", not completely suported by every browser

Comment: can you show where are you using the console.log()?

Comment: yes @ChandraShekhar

Comment: @SaraNekonam, add this line to your code at the end " console.log(list);"

Comment: @ChandraShekhar i want show them in body html

Comment: just read your question title.. does console mean body of html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be caused due to getting "element" that is not exist in the DOM.
Call your Javascript code after your body tag.
e.g

```
<body>

<div id="des"></div>

</body>


<script>
  var howMany = prompt("how many do you want to buy?");
  var goods = "";
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0 ; i < howMany ; i++){
  goods = prompt("add a name ?");
  list.push(goods);
```

}

```
  var show = document.getElementById("des");
  show.innerText = list;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var howMany = prompt("how many do you want to buy?");
  var goods = "";
  var list = [];
  for (var i = 0 ; i < howMany ; i++){
  goods = prompt("add a name ?");
  list.push(goods);
  }
 var show = document.getElementById("des");
  show.innerText = list;
```

```html
<div id="des"></div>
```

Try This